Book where it’s a maze filled with paintings
It’s this book where a ladder leads to an underground maze and the maze is filled with old paintings but they all look the same depending on where you go in the maze but if you make it to the other side, it’s another ladder that would take you back in time. I remember this book from like 10 or so years ago.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember the cover of the book at all?  What do you mean that the paintings "all look the same depending on where you go?"  All the paintings change identically as you move?

Vaguely reminds me of Piranesi by Susanna Clarke, but that was a maze filled with statues, not paintings.

For some reason this reminds me of the description of wandering through corridors in the House Absolute in Gene Wolfe's "Book of the New Sun".  The "other side" of some of the paintings is in another time.

@Ethan I was thinking that too.  I'm surprised to see it in a comment though because I didnt think other people would think of The House Absolute.
